# Returning Data from a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value

I would like to ask how am I going to return the `count(*)` because every time I call the stored procedure, it just prints the result.

Here is the code :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_returnCount
    @tblname sysname
    , @colname sysname
    , @key varchar(10) 
AS
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @num INT
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR (4000)

    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) ' +
              ' FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tblname) + 
              ' WHERE ' + quotename(@colname) + ' LIKE @key'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@key varchar(10)', @key
    --just prints 5 or any numbers...
```

I'd like to return the `count(*)` to use it in another query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried RETURN @@Rowcount

Comment: Yes you're right there. I tried it and it worked. Thanks @Dijkgraaf

Comment: make sure @@Rowcount is immediately after the statement. Else you might not get the required result. Alternativley, assign it to another variable for use in later part of your query or stored procedure

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_returnCount
    @tblname sysname
    , @colname sysname
    , @key varchar(10)
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @num INT
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR (4000) 
DECLARE @count int

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT @count = COUNT(*) ' +
              ' FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tblname) + 
              ' WHERE ' + quotename(@colname) + ' LIKE @key'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@key varchar(10), @count int OUTPUT', @key, @count OUTPUT
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Looking forward to asking more questions to you. :)